# Testing for XSS vulnerabilities when URl contains hidden fields

Tags: xss

i am checking for XSS vulnerabilities for my portal. the examples that i found on internet says that, if you have a URl like this

```
http://www.yoursite.com/index.html?name=george
```

try encoding it like

```
http://www.yoursite.com/index.html?name=<script>alert('You just found a XSS vulnerability')</script>
```

and if you find alert , it will show that your portal is XSS vulnerable.
but my question is my url doesn't contains any variable , as i am using hidden fields
my url looks like

```
http://[myip]:8080/appshop-V1/appStoreRegistration.html
```

and it doesn't changes on any post or get operation .how can i insert script in such scenario and check for vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The basic safety tells that you should not trust the input coming from user , they can use the tools like fiddler and easily manipulate the hidden field value also. If you are using that value to output something on your portal like name etc...do the html encode before outputting it. XSS is not limited to querystring , it can be anything that is coming from user. Even it is advisable that you should not store the sensitive information in the hidden field because end user can see it and change it .

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking if your form processor only accepts POST requests, then XSSing it is a little difficult (see http://blog.portswigger.net/2007/03/exploiting-xss-in-post-requests.html for an example how). If you only want to test instead of creating a full exploit, then use a tool that allows you to modify request fields (e.g. Burp Suite from the link above) and play with it.

If your postback URL responds to both POST and GET requests (it shouldn't, but this happens all the time), then simply add your "post" variables into the URL as in your first example and XSS through them. Variables can be seen in the HTML  elements inside your .

Some advanced reading is at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

In short, get a scanner, this is not worth doing by hand.